# UITableview deallocation crashes with KVO error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, dealloc

I am using UITableview for a chat inbox view and my navigation stack is like

```
(
    "<VTDiscoverHome3ViewController: 0x7ff094758f00>",
    "<VTInboxViewController: 0x7ff098de34d0>",
    "<VTChatViewController: 0x7ff095827e00>",
    "<VTDiscoverProfessionalDetailsViewController: 0x7ff095424a00>",
    "<VTRequestScheduleViewController: 0x7ff095814c00>"
)
```

So while popping to home view from top view I am getting a crash in inbox view saying

```
An instance 0x7ff094a33800 of class UITableView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x608002e3f680> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x60800585c1d0: Observer: 0x7ff098f1b8d0, Key path: contentOffset, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x60800585c140>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x60800585c320: Observer: 0x7ff098f1b8d0, Key path: contentSize, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x60800585c290>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x60800585c410: Observer: 0x7ff098f1b8d0, Key path: frame, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x60800585c380>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x60800585c500: Observer: 0x7ff098f1b8d0, Key path: contentInset, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x60800585c470>
)'
```

I tried removing `tableview` observers and setting

```
self.tableView.delegate = nil;
self.tableView.dataSource = nil;
self.tableView = nil;
```

but still no luck

I dont understand why am I getting this crash.

Any help would be much appreciable.

Thanks.

Comment: have you added any Key Value Observer for any Properties for the said ViewController?

Comment: Nope I have not.

Comment: How did you remove `tableView` observers

Comment: `[self.tableView removeFromSuperView];` try this ,,,,,

Comment: @K.R.SaravanaKumar If I remove tableview observers app crashes saying these properties are not added as observers.

Comment: @Dhiru App crashes if i do that.

Comment: @ParasGorasiya remove those observers in dealloc function using try catch like this '-(void)dealloc{
    try { // there should be At symbol before try
        // Code to Remove Observers
    } catch (NSException *exception) { // there should be At symbol catch try
    } finally { // there should be At symbol before finally
    }
}'

Comment: Your try and catch solution works but the actual problem was different, I'll post it as an answer to this question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.

I am using a pull to refresh class which adds some observers to `tableview`'s `scrollview`

So while deallocation sometimes it was crashing.

So, added `try` and `catch` block when removing `observers`.